# Is a bad idea to use HTMLUnit to every first HttpRequest?

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, htmlunit, web-crawler

I have a ajax frontend for my java backend, and to make things work with the crawls and `HTML5` pushState I going to use `HtmlUnit` to process the javascript in every first request.

I can make a workaround with a Filter to not use `HtmlUnit` trying to reduce the server load.

Regardless of browser compatibility, which is best for the server?

Comment: Google recommend that approach -  see point 3 on https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/html-snapshot , although I guess it depends on quite how much of your content is generated.

Comment: All my content is javascript generated, I have only a html file which I insert templates into, with Backbone and underscore.

Comment: Google approach is to use hashbang, but I going with pushState, thats the problem. PushState requires that the first request to the server returns the fully processed html file.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research and test I can tell that process heavy javascript applications on server side ins't I good idea, HtmlUnit is the best tool around and it doesn't do the job very well, so if your requirements are to support clients that doesn't support javascript, so go for PHP or some other server side script language or maybe JSF.

I my case, I have a Back-end in JAX-RS and I manage to support HTML5 pushState without process the javascript on server-side and assume that the client process javascript, HtmlUnit still in use for enable crawlability.